# How to set the Content-Type to "application/json" for Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2 HttpRequest in c#?

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm using the package `google.cloud.tasks.v2` to enqueue a task in a Google App Engine Task Queue. The documentation states:

> If the task has a body, Cloud Tasks sets the following headers:
>
> `Content-Type`: By default, the `Content-Type` header is set to
> `"application/octet-stream"`. The default can be overridden by
> explicitly setting `Content-Type` to a particular media type when the
> task is created. For example, `Content-Type` can be set to
> `"application/json"`.

The text "when the task is created" links [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#google.cloud.tasks.v2.CloudTasks.CreateTask), which does not go into detail about how to change the Content-Type from the default of `"application/octet-stream"`. Much Google searching always leads back to the above link.

The task has an `HttpRequest` property, which has a `Headers` property, but it is read only.

Here's my code so far:

```
CloudTasksClient cloudTasksClient = CloudTasksClient.Create();
var task = cloudTasksClient.CreateTask(new CreateTaskRequest
{
    Parent = parent.ToString(),
    Task = new Task
    {
        HttpRequest = new HttpRequest
        {
            HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
            Url = url,
            Body = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchToDo)),
        },
        //ScheduleTime = Timestamp.FromDateTime(
        //           DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(inSeconds))
    }
});
```

How can I set the `Content-Type` to `"application/json"` for the `HttpRequest`?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what error have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question, the [`Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2.HttpRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2/latest/Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2.HttpRequest)  has a readonly `Headers` property which is [`MapField`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Protobuf/latest/Google.Protobuf.Collections.MapField-2.html). While the property is readonly, `MapField` does have an `Add()` method, which you can use to add the header you need.

Create the `HttpRequest` and add the header before creating the `Task`:

```
CloudTasksClient cloudTasksClient = CloudTasksClient.Create();
// create HttpRequest
HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest
{
    HttpMethod = Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2.HttpMethod.Post,
    Url = url,
    Body = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchToDo)),
};
// add Content-Type to headers
httpReq.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

var task = cloudTasksClient.CreateTask(new CreateTaskRequest
{
    Parent = parent.ToString(),
    Task = new Task
    {
        HttpRequest = httpReq,  // assign the HttpRequest
        ...
    }
});
```

<sup>**Note**: I don't use google cloud platform, this is untested and based purely on the docs found online.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `.putHeaders()` builder method can be used to set the headers for the HTTP tasks:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()                                        
                    .setUrl(url)
                    .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .putHeaders("key", "value")
                    .build();
```